# Independency of a set in matroid theory

Tags: matroids

Suppose $M=(X,I)$ be a matroid , $X=\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ and $$Y=\{x_i\mid \operatorname{rank}(\{x_1,...,x_i\}) > \operatorname{rank}(\{x_1,...,x_{i-1}\}) \}$$ then $Y$ is in I.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Is there a difference between $y$ and $Y$? If not, the statement "$y$ is in $I$ or $Y$ is an independent set" is a tautology. If yes, what is $y$?

Comment: @Randy Marsh Oh,it's my fault.they are the same.

Comment: Do you know that $\operatorname{rank}A=|A|$ iff $A\in I$, and that for any $x\in X$, $\operatorname{rank}A\le\operatorname{rank}(A\cup\{x\})\le\operatorname{rank}A+1$?

Comment: @scott yes but I use it when I want to prove something is a basis for a matroid, now we know that rank(A union {xi})=rank A+1, but how should I continue?

Comment: Then we have Y has elements  (A union {xi}) in I or {xi} in I because it's subset should be in I, is it correct?